# Correct structure for "static" type objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, properties, scope, static

I'm struggling to get to grips with creating "static" object types in JavaScript (I doubt I've even worded that correctly...).

In the following code, I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin (I suspect that is irrelevant, though), which creates multiple `CrmQuery` each with their own contextual information passed in as `instance`. I also want to create a "static" object for all the `CrmQuery` to use (it can be stateless), and was hoping to contain it within the `CrmQuery` namespace.

This is the structure I have, but when calling `CrmQuery.searchOperator[instance.Operator].buildCondition(instance.fieldName, searchTerm)`, the `buildCondition` function doesn't have access to the `oDataOperator` function in `CrmQuery.searchOperator`. I've tried referencing it in many ways, not just `searchOperator.oDataOperator`, and `this` is a reference to the actual property, not `CrmQuery.searchOperator`.

Structure:

```
(function($) { 
...
var crmQuery = new CrmQuery(instance);
var data = crmQuery.searchCrm(searchTerm);
... 

var CrmQuery = function(instance) {
    ...
    this.oDataUrl = function() {
        ...
        oDataFilter += CrmQuery.searchOperator[instance.Operator].buildCondition(instance.fieldName, searchTerm);
        ...
        return oDataFilter;
    }();

    this.searchCrm(searchTerm) {
        ...
        url += this.oDataUrl;
    }
    ...
}

CrmQuery.searchOperator = {
    oDataFunctionOperator: function oDataFunctionOperator(fieldName, searchTerm, operator) {
        return operator + "(" + fieldName + ", '" + searchTerm + "')";
    },
    oDataOperator: function oDataOperator(fieldName, searchTerm, operator) {
        return fieldName + " " + operator + " '" + searchTerm +"'";
    },
    STARTSWITH: { 
        operator: "startswith", 
        buildCondition: function(fieldName, searchTerm) { 
                return this.oDataFunctionOperator(fieldName, searchTerm, this.operator) 
            }
    },
    ENDSWITH: { 
        operator: "endswith", 
        buildCondition: function(fieldName, searchTerm) { 
                return searchOperator.oDataFunctionOperator(fieldName, searchTerm, this.operator) 
            }
    },
    CONTAINS: { 
        operator: "substringof", 
        buildCondition: function(fieldName, searchTerm) { 
                return searchOperator.oDataFunctionOperator(fieldName, searchTerm, this.operator) 
            }
    },
    EXACTMATCH: { 
        operator: "eq", 
        buildCondition: function(fieldName, searchTerm) { 
                return searchOperator.oDataOperator(fieldName, searchTerm, this.operator) 
            }
    },
    toString: function () {
        var thisVar = this;
        var output = "searchOperator enum. ";
        output += $.map(Object.keys(this), function (i) {
            if (typeof thisVar[i] !== "function") 
                return i + ": " + thisVar[i].operator;
        }).join(", ");
        return output;
    }
}
...
}(jQuery));
```

What is the correct way to implement a pattern like this in JavaScript?

I hope this makes sense? Apologies if it's too verbose, but I didn't want to leave anything out that may be important.

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

inheritance is one way to solve this, for example:

```
function searchOperator() {
}

//searchOperator.prototype.toString = ...

functionOperator = function(operator) {
    searchOperator.apply(this);
    this.operator = operator;
}

functionOperator.prototype = Object.create(searchOperator.prototype);

functionOperator.prototype.buildCondition = function (fieldName, searchTerm) {
    return this.operator + "(" + fieldName + ", '" + searchTerm + "')";
}

operators = {

    STARTSWITH: new functionOperator('startswith')
}

console.log(operators.STARTSWITH.buildCondition('foo', 'bar'))
```

Comment: Thanks georg. Would I be declaring all of that within the `CrmQuery` function, or would they sit outside of it? Also, I'm not quite understanding the logic - is functionOperator inheriting from searchOperator, but with a `buildCondition` function added?

Comment: Also, the operator is supposed to indicate to `buildCondition` which function to use to build itself with. How is that being done in your example, as you have `buildCondition` as a actual code, as opposed to calling the operator specific function?

Comment: `searchOperator` is an abstract class, which doesn't know how to build conditions. I coded operators like `STARTSWITH` as instances of `functionOperator`, but they also can be subclasses with their specific functionality